# Custom BSP for SRM UI Addon

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to create a custom BSP application for SRM UI Addon instead of injecting pieces of code using custom JS/CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. After you maintain the custom BSP application, you will need to put the JS/CSS files you would like to be loaded in the customizing.

Comment: So I can actually just edit the JS/CSS files in my custom BSP and that system will read that BSP instead? Do I still need to add the custom files via SPRO?